# Which pairing programs have been authorized by FIDE for use in FIDE rated tournaments?

Tags: software, fide, swiss-pairing

There are lots of questions about pairing programs here, some of them mention being *authorized by FIDE*, but how can I check and know which programs are currently authorized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FIDE publish a list of such programs [here](https://handbook.fide.com/files/handbook/C04Annex3_FEP19.pdf).

Currently there are 10 programs on the list varying in price from completely free (Tornelo, STOP), free on Linux (Vega), partially free (ChessManager) to 150 euros (Swiss Manager). Two of them are web-based (Tornelo, ChessManager) and the remainder are desktop software.

**Program** - **Author**
[Tornelo](https://home.tornelo.com/) - *Tornelo (AUS)*
[Vega](http://vegachess.com/) - *Luigi Forlano (ITA)*
[SwissSys](http://swisssys.com/) - *Thad Suits (USA)*
[SwissMaster](http://schaakbond.nl/swissmaster) - *Royal Dutch Chess Federation (NED)*
[Swiss-Manager](http://swiss-manager.at/) - *Heinz Herzog (AUT)*
[Swiss-Chess](http://swiss-chess.de/) - *Franz-Josef Weber (GER)*
[UTU Swiss](http://utuswiss.co.uk/) - *Neil Hayward (UK)*
[ChessManager](https://www.chessmanager.com/en/solutions/software) - *Tomasz Żyźniewski (POL)*
[STOP](https://www.freebasic-portal.de/downloads/anwendungssoftware/schachturnierorganisationsprogramm-233.html) - *Alexander Lenhard (GER)*
[Tournament Service](https://tournamentservice.com/) - *Harald Heggelund (NOR)*
The landing experience also varies widely. Most are excellent, giving you useful information about provided functionality and limitations upfront, but some are appalling.